# Connecting multiple LAN's together

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, dhcp

I have a fairly robust homelab, and I'm trying to "mesh" an independent LAN into my current setup. Long story short, I have my home network that runs great, and a camper trailer that has its own network. I've bridged the two, but I get all sorts of weird routing issues (that I think are dhcp related) when the camper LAN is connected.

- Primary network:

  - Bridged modem
  - Pfsense box (dchp server)
  - Adguard vm
  - Ubiquiti switch
  - Ubiquiti AP's
  - Unraid NAS
  - Asus wifi bridge to camper (hard-wired to ub switch)
  - Dhcp segment 192.x.x.70-254
- Camper LAN:

  - Windows pc for dhcp/jellyfin
  - Wifi router running in Bridge mode
  - Dhcp provided by Windows machine
  - Dhcp segment 192.x.x.50-70

Basically I'd like my camper to mesh into my network when it's home so it can have media copied loacally to it from unraid, and be able see the internet so jellyfin can scrape the media it's being fed. When the camper is away, it's should be able to serve dhcp leases to clients on the asus router.

When the camper is home and is meshing to the main network, it always seems to hand out dhcp addresses on the main network, and plays havok with the rest of the networks WAN connectivity.

I feel like VLAN's maybe the solution here, but I haven't dived into them before.

Any advice before I start learning about VLAN's and trying to implement that?

Cheers!

Comment: Does Jellyfin require the media source being on the same subnet? Generally it shouldn't, but is that e.g. mentioned as a requirement in docs? Do _you_ require all the devices to be in a single subnet instead of two interconnected subnets each having its own DHCP? (In general, being able to deal with multiple subnets needs to come _before_ learning VLANs, as it builds on that – each vlan would be its own subnet.)

Comment: `192.x.x` ... is the first x 168? if so, then you don't need to hide the IP's since 192.168.x.x are private addresses

Comment: The only real requirements are for the camper network to be able to access the nas (for copying files to its local storage) and the internet (for scraping media). Perhaps subnets are the way to go, ill have a look. unsure how you access the NAS over multiple subnets, ill have a look into that !

Comment: First learn how to route between networks. VLANs are great for putting multiple networks into a single wire, but you'll usually need to route between them as well, whilst I don't see a need to put several networks into single wire in the first place. Learn routing, not VLANs.